# How to dispatch Job from other Job in Laravel with arbitrary delay?

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-5, jobs

I have two jobs, the first pushes notifications to drivers and they have to choose if the accept the itinerary or not. And the second job is to award the itinerary on a interested driver. I want to dispatch the second job with delay 1 minute after the notification be pushed.

Below, is the first job which pushes the notifications:

```
class NewBookingNotification extends Job implements ShouldQueue, BookingAwardCallback
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, DispatchesJobs;

    protected $booking;
    protected $admin;

    public function __construct(Booking $booking, User $admin)
    {
        $this->booking = $booking;
        $this->admin = $admin;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        Log::info('new booking started ' . $this->booking->id);

        $delay = $this->admin->notification_expire_time; // 60 seconds

        echo "handle new booking \n";

        $awardJob = new AwardNotification($this->booking, $this->admin, $this);
        $driversCount = TempBookingDriver::where(['booking_id' => $this->booking->id, 'awarded' => 1])->get()->count('*');

        if ($driversCount < $this->booking->vehicles_quantity) {
            $notifiedDriversCount = NotificationsHelper::pushNewBooking($this->booking, $this->admin);
            if ($notifiedDriversCount > 0) {
                $this->award($delay, $awardJob);
            } else {
                Utils::call($this->admin, $this->booking->id, Utils::getClientName($this->booking));
            }
        } else {
            $this->award($delay, $awardJob);
        }

        if ($this->attempts() > 1)
            Utils::call($this->admin, $this->booking->id, Utils::getClientName($this->booking));
    }

    private function award($delay, $job)
    {
        // queue award job
        Queue::later($delay, $job);
    }

    public function releaseNewBookingJob()
    {
        $this->release();
        Log::info('new booking job released (Log)');
    }

    public function deleteNewBookingJob()
    {
        $this->delete();
        Log::info('new booking job stopped (Log)');
    }

    public function queue($queue, $command)
    {
        $id = $queue->pushOn('default', $command);

        $bookingJob = new BookingJob();
        $bookingJob->booking_id = $this->booking->id;
        $bookingJob->job_id = $id;
        $bookingJob->save();
    }
}
```

And the second job for driver award:

```
class AwardNotification extends Job implements ShouldQueue
{
    use InteractsWithQueue, SerializesModels, DispatchesJobs;

    protected $callback;
    protected $booking;
    protected $admin;

    public function __construct(Booking $booking, User $admin, BookingAwardCallback $callback)
    {
        $this->booking = $booking;
        $this->admin = $admin;
        $this->callback = $callback;
    }

    public function handle()
    {
        echo "handle award booking \n";
        $awardedDrivers = NotificationsHelper::pushNewAward($this->booking, $this->admin);
        if ($awardedDrivers > 0) {
            $this->callback->deleteNewBookingJob();
        } else {
            $this->callback->releaseNewBookingJob();
        }
    }
}
```

Now, the problem is that when `NewBookingNotification` job tries to queue the `AwardNotification` job, it "fails" and it releases itself. When I comment `award` it doesn't release itself. Is there any other way to dispatch the second job?

Comment: What queue driver are you using?

Comment: According to Laravel documentation you should be able to dispatch your job like so: http://pastebin.com/Cj6BnM8V

Comment: I'm using database driver, the problem was the `deleteNewBookingJob` and `releaseNewBookingJob`. When I removed these functions it worked